# Import node module in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, import, npm, node-modules

How can I import a module, e.g. `pikaday` from another one, e.g. `handsontable` in `angularjs` from the node_modules?

```
import {pikaday} from handsontable
```

doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you using angular1, then you should also add them as dependencies:

`angular.module('YourApp', ['ngHandsontable','pikaday']);`

2. If you using angular2, then it should be like:

`import { Pikaday } from 'picaday'`, you can [Read more](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1342) here

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using angular1. Should I also import it
`import 'pikaday'` ?
It still seems to not be found (after also importing it). I'm getting this error:
`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'pikaday'`

Comment: no need of import in angular1, just add reference to your html. like `<script src="ngHandsontable.js"></script>`, and add dependecies to your module like `angular.module('YourApp', ['ngHandsontable','pikaday']);` [ReadMore](https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable), [pikaday](https://github.com/nverba/pikaday-angular)